# How to encypt username and password in flutter

Tags: encryption, flutter, public-key-encryption, password-encryption, flutter-dependencies

am trying to implement phone_number and password encryption in flutter. after have tried to encrypt the jsonbody "(
    var rBody = jsonEncode({ 'Request': encryptor.encrypt(requestBody.toString())});" and then run the app am still unable to transmit the request to my remote server(which requires all requests to be encrypted with AES). Can someone with experience on this show me the best way to do this. such that the password and phone are encrypted effectively.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;



  Future<http.Response> post() async {
var url = 'http:xxxxxxxpostRequest';
String password = "xxxxxxx";//url password
String username = "xxxxx";//access username

var bytes = utf8.encode("$username:$password");


var credentials = base64.encode(bytes);
var headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Basic $credentials"
};

var requestBody = jsonEncode({ 'phone': _phone, 'pin': _pass});

final key = "";// encryption key
final iv= "";

final encryptor=new Encrypter(new Salsa20(key, iv));


var rBody = jsonEncode({ 'Request': encryptor.encrypt(requestBody.toString())});


http.Response response = await http.post(
    url, body: rBody, headers: headers);
var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
print(Utf8Codec().decode(response.bodyBytes));

print("Body: " + responseJson);
```

}

//This is my console response

E/flutter (24909): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (24909): type 'ParametersWithIV' is not a subtype of type 'ParametersWithIV'
E/

Comment: Does the server require AES or Salsa20? If AES, which blocking and padding algorithms? CBC? PKCS5Padding?

Comment: Hey Richard am using CBC/PKCS5 padding

Comment: As you know, AES keys are typically 128 or 256 bits and IVs are 128 bits. How is the server expecting you to derive the key and IV from the strings you show in your snippet?

Comment: the strings are not the exact keys.I have the exact Strings .  what am inquiring  is what is the effective way to do it. for instance a working example using the same format.

Comment: Are to the strings you have in hex? You have to convert them first to bytes. Has the server team told you how they are expecting you to convert them to 16 bytes?

Comment: Yeah, but am just concerned with how you should construct the encryption code in dart. would you kindly share an example regardless of the key Strings please?

Comment: Just a quick question: I assume you are posting to an https url. If the POST is  already encrypted by means of SSL/TLS, why do we still need to encrypt it again?

Answer (score 2):

The `encrypt` package isn't well maintained, so use the `pointy castle` package. (Use `pointycastle: ^1.0.0-rc3`.)

Your question isn't clear about how you are going to:

- derive the key material from the strings provided
- convert the plaintext to bytes
- convert the cipher text back to something you can include in json

They could be encoded in hex or base64 perhaps. Your server team should be able to specify what they want.

Here's example code to encrypt in AES/CBC/PKCS7.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:pointycastle/api.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/paddings/pkcs7.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/aes_fast.dart';
import 'package:pointycastle/block/modes/cbc.dart';

main() {
  //final key = 'dxxxxxxxxxxeX';
  //final iv = '_Vxxxxxxxxxx1';

  // TODO - convert the key and IV to bytes
  // dummy key and IV values
  Uint8List key = Uint8List.fromList(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
  );
  Uint8List iv = Uint8List.fromList(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
  );

  // TODO - convert the plaintext to bytes
  // example - just utf8 encode it
  Uint8List plainText = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode('some plain text'));

  PaddedBlockCipher cipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(
    PKCS7Padding(),
    CBCBlockCipher(AESFastEngine()),
  );

  cipher.init(
    true,
    PaddedBlockCipherParameters<CipherParameters, CipherParameters>(
      ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>(KeyParameter(key), iv),
      null,
    ),
  );
  Uint8List cipherText = cipher.process(plainText);
  // TODO - convert the cipher text to a String to include as the 'Request' param
}
```

PS Don't forget that it's insecure to reuse the same IV more than once.